# How to evaluate $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}$ in terms of $\alpha = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to evaluate :

$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}$

In terms of the number:

$\alpha = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$

What I am thinking is that $\cos(x) = \frac{\sin(2x)}{2\sin(x)}$

But I don't know if this is the correct beginning

One example (I am doing this just to show that I can't derivate) I already did was:

$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin(ax)}{\sin(bx)} =\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin(ax)\cdot bx\cdot a}{ax\cdot \sin(bx)\cdot b} = \alpha \cdot \frac{1}{\alpha}\cdot\frac{a}{b} = \frac{a}{b}$

Comment: You could just apply L’Hospital’s rule (if allowed)

Comment: Yes WW1, but as I stated on my example, I am not allowed to derivate, with L'Hopital it would be 1/2 I guess, but that doesn't work for me.

Comment: You could try to use that $[1-\cos(x)][1+\cos(x)] = \sin^2(x)$ to show that the limit is equal the limit of $\frac{1}{1+\cos(x)}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$
1-\cos x=2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}\Rightarrow \lim_{x\to0} \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}{x^2}=?
$$

Comment: Thanks! The answer with this is **$\frac{\alpha^2}{2}$**

Comment: @JulioMadrigal Correct.